# Python Django not showing stack trace

Tags: python, django, stack-trace

I installed a fresh copy of `Python 3.4` and `Django 1.8.2` on my Windows 7 machine.

In my `settings.py` file `DEBUG` is set to `True`.

My admin page is working. I am using the built-in web server.

The problem is when I try to open an existing page in the project I get `"Error 500"` and no stack trace so I can fix the issue.

Opening non-existent pages also ends up with no stack trace and only `"Error 404"`.

Comment: What are you using to run Django? Are you using manage.py runserver or a web server? 500s and 404s will often not give stack traces, as 500 is an internal server error code and a 404 is page not found (however, if you're using Django's 404 handlers incorrectly, you will get a stack trace).

Comment: I am using "python manage.py runserver". 
On another machine I installed exactly the same setup (python + django) and it gave me some feedback (stack trace) when errors happened.

Answer (score 1):

In **settings.py**. Add these(for development)

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this and nothing different happened.

Comment: that works for me. the key is to set  `django.request`'s `propagate` to  True.

if necessary, try use a "StreamHandler" . FYI  @itzMEonTV

Comment: that works for me. the key is to set  `django.request`'s `propagate` to  True.

if necessary, try use a "StreamHandler" . FYI  @itzMEonTV