# How to solve CreateAPI 400 error in this DjangoRestFramework in Serializer Create Method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a model, Doctor, that has a Foreign key relation to the user model. I'm handling the creation of Doctor instances through the serializer of the Doctor Model. The flow I'm going for is simply to check if a user with the given username exists. If it exists, then create a new Doctor Instance with the existing user, if it doesn't, then first create a new user, and then create a Doctor Instance with that new user.
Here is my Doctor Serializer :->

```
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for viewing entries Doctor model
    """

    departments_display = DepartmentSerializer(
        many=True, source="departments", read_only=True
    )
    appointment_types_display = AppointmentTypeSerializer(
        many=True, source="appointment_types", read_only=True
    )
    user = UserSerializer()
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
    doc_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        exclude = ("hospitals",)
        extra_kwargs = {
            "departments": {"write_only": True},
            "appointment_types": {"required": False},
        }
    
    def get_doc_image(self,obj):
        return obj.doctor_image
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Doctor` instance, given the validated data.
        """
      #  try:
        with transaction.atomic():
                user_data = validated_data.pop("user")
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(username = user_data["username"])
                    validated_data["user"] = user
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    serializer = UserSerializer(data = user_data)
                    if serializer.is_valid():
                       serializer.save()
                    validated_data["user"] = serializer.instance
                permmissions = validated_data.pop("permissions")
                permissions_to_insert = []
                for permission_entry in permmissions:
                    uiserializer = UIElementSerializer(data = permission_entry["ui_element"])
                    uiserializer.is_valid()
                    uiserializer.save()
                    permissions_to_insert.append(
                        StaffPermissions(
                            ui_element=uiserializer.instance,
                            create=permission_entry["create"],
                            read=permission_entry["read"],
                            update=permission_entry["update"],
                            delete=permission_entry["delete"],
                        )
                    )
                permission_instance = StaffPermissions.objects.bulk_create(
                    permissions_to_insert
                )
                doc_obj = super().create(validated_data)
                doc_obj.permissions.add(*permission_instance)
                return doc_obj
        #except Exception as e:
         #   raise APIException()
```

Here are the user and Doctor models:->

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name_hi = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=127)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_ROLES, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True
    )
    push_tokens = models.ManyToManyField(PushNotificationToken, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ""


class Doctor(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #User = get_user_model()
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admitting_officer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    practice_started_year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1023)
    about_hi = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1023)
    credentials = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(
        Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hospital_doctor"
    )
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(StaffPermissions, blank=True)
    appointment_types = models.ManyToManyField("appointments.AppointmentTypes")
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLES, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here's the View:-

```
 class StaffView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      

        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
        serializer_class = StaffSerializer
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            try:
                if self.request.GET.get("hospital_id"):
                    return Doctor.objects.filter(
                        hospital=self.request.GET.get("hospital_id")
                    ).order_by("-modified_date")
                else:
                    return Doctor.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            except ValueError as exc:
                raise APIException(
                    "Please send in a valid hospital id and/or doctor id."
                ) from exc
```

When I create a new Doctor Instance, it keeps throwing the error, that a user with this user already exists. This is very hard to believe as I'm using a try-exception block to verify if a user exists or not and then taking appropriate actions.
Here's the exact error block->

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": [
      "A user with that username already exists."
    ]
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me out with this?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) instead of ObjectDoesNotExist, similar to this:

```
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username = user_data["username"])
                validated_data["user"] = user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                serializer = UserSerializer(data = user_data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                   serializer.save()
                validated_data["user"] = serializer.instance
```

This may solve the problem.

You can try [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for this particular use-case.

Comment: Tried both of them, still throws the same error

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace and exact error, so we can try to diagnose the problem

Comment: Okay I edited the exact error on my terminal, glad for your help!

Comment: Can you try to use filter() and first() clause to check and proceed.
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KD3kWEjZ). If this doesn't help, Please paste the stacktrace. 
[How to enable stack trace in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693145/python-django-not-showing-stack-trace)